# Problem with my partitions?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ubuntu-11.04

I needed to split my hard disk into 5 partitions for installing Ubuntu 11.04. The firs one (*) was for system reserved - 100mb, second (C) was the installation of Windows 7, third (D) was for my work files, fourth (E) was for my multimedia (pictures, music etc.) and the last one was for Ubuntu 11.04. After doing so, some warning appeared telling me something about "can't boot..."  I don't remember (stupid of me), and after doing so, all partitions got simple volume and not primary partition, even where my operating system is. The system is booting correctly and working correctly but it is kind of weird, is there any way to change it to primary partition? I used EASEUS Partition Master Home edition to convert them safely, but the option isn't there to use!!! So I have two questions, first:

What happened with my partitions and is it worth converting them? What are the cons and pros about simple and primary partitions?

And the second question:

How to install Ubuntu 11.04 to another partition like I done so far ( but when I boot with the Ubuntu cd I burned) to recognize the free space or the recently made partitions, not only two like before (it recognized only two partition, one was C and the second was E )?

I know is long question (2 questions) but I'm really desperate to fix this two  problems...

Answer (score 1):

As you can only have 4 primary partitions in your partition table, your partitioning program created an extended partition to contain more (logical) partitions.

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/forum/installation/Partitioning Ubuntu can be installed to a logical partition without repercussions.

One way you could resolve this is by transfering data from a primary partition to a logical partition and then install Ubuntu to the primary partition. There is probably a better way to do this, because my way involves a lot of file transfers and etc.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: As you can use Ubuntu on a logical partition like you would on a primary partition, I wouldn't change anything. It is not worth the hassle ...

Comment: Logical partitions and (W7) simple volumes are not the same thing. And beside that, if you have 4 primary partitions, you can't add an extended one, as the extended partition count as one primary.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting back from simple volumes to partitions is not easily possible without reformatting the entire disk and changing it back from dynamic disk to base disk, or use a 3rd party tool.

FYI: http://www.dynamic-disk.com/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html